# cannot compile function template instantiation containing "if constexpr"

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, constexpr

Sorry for the vague title, but I couldn't come up with a better one.

I wrote a function to flatten containers:

```
template <typename Container, typename OutIt>
void flatten(const Container& container, OutIt res)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<typename Container::value_type, typename std::iterator_traits<OutIt>::value_type>)
    {
        for (const auto& value : container)
        {
            *res = value;
            ++res;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (const auto& subContainer : container)
            flatten(subContainer, res);
    }
}
```

And I wanted it to be used like:

```
vector<vector<int>> test = {{1}, {2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7}};
vector<int> res;
flatten(test, std::back_inserter(res));
```

This should basically copy all the nested values from `test` to `res`, so that `res == { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }`.

However, if I want to compile the code, the compiler throws some errors which basically say, that the code in the `else` branch gets compiled instead of the `if constexpr` block.

I.e. The first instantiation is `void flatten<vector<vector<int>>, OutIt>()` which is correct. The second instantiation (which is triggered by the `else` block) is `void flatten<vector<int>, OutIt>()` which is also correct. But for the 2nd instantiation, the `if constexpr` expression should evaluate to `true`, as `vector<int>::value_type` is `int` and `std::iterator_traits<OutIt>::value_type>` is also `int`. But somehow the compiler tries to instantiate a third template `void flatten<int, OutIt>()` which causes the compiler errors (because I try to iterate over an integer).

Why does the compiler instantiate the 3rd template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass in a [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), for which `value_type` is `void`. So your true branch of the if statement is never instantiated.

A possible solution would be to try checking for what the branch does. This may be done with [`std::is_assignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable) and some boilerplate involving `decltype(*declval<OutIt>())`.

Comment: Great, thanks. I changed the expression to `std::is_assignable_v<decltype(*std::declval<OutIt>()), typename Container::value_type>` and it works like a charm.